# Are questions about recommendations to avoid unlocking on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

Reffering to this item of the [off-topic list in the help section](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"

I would like to ask this:

> It already happened three times. My Motorola XT890 locked itself from being kept in the pocket, showing the 'too many password attempts' screen and requiring Internet connection to get unlocked via a Google Account.
>
> If there's no Internet connection active when it got locked, the system won't offer a standard way of activate it to be able to authenticate, leaving us to a factory reset and some other [complicated ways to bypass this problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848).
>
> Thinking about *avoiding* getting into this situation again, what choices do I have among apps and configuration settings with the *unlocked* phone?

Is it too speculative and off-topic?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it would seem like you could simply not ask *What apps can I choose from?*, but instead ask a more general *How can I prevent this?* If the solution happens to be an app, then people will typicaly be more than happy to suggest one to you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change the question and ask.